# Does the errata-ed Magic missile always kill a minion?

Tags: dnd-4e

As many know, magic missile does not have a `hit` section anymore, just an effect:

```
Effect: 2 + Intelligence modifier force damage.
```

Does that mean that a minion is auto-killed by magic missile?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**,

The glossary definition of a minion is:

> - A minion is destroyed when it takes any damage.
> - If a minion is missed by an attack that deals damage on a miss, the minion doesn’t take that damage.

In short, minions are immune from damage on the **Miss** line, but not from **Hit**, or **Effect**.  (Magic Missile deals its damage via the **Effect** line)

Comment: Are you sure about this? Isn't damage on the effect line "an attack that deals damage on a miss"? MM is not affected because it doesn't hit or miss, it just has an effect.

Comment: @Snowbody effect != miss, they are different.

Answer (score 7):

As long as the minion does not have sufficient force resistance to negate the damage, or any other mechanism by which they may interrupt or avoid it, the answer is yes.

Comment: minion zombie vs mm.. joy!